# How can Customer make payment for Admin Created Order

Tags: magento2.3, payment, magento-community

How can a Customer make Payment if Admin has created Order on Behalf of Customer?

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/customers/customer-account-create-order.html

Comment: are there any constraints about using specific payment methods? or are you in search of possible solutions that can solve your problem?

Comment: @DianaBotean thanks for replying. No, no contraints about payment methods. Just want to know after an Admin (i.e, ShopOwner team) has placed order on behalf of Customer. Then how will Customer go about making the payment for that Order?

Answer (score 0):

In a default Magento install, you can use several approaches to achieve this by using some of the offline payment methods:

1. The customer can make the payment in advance and the admin can place the order on behalf of the customer and choose the **[Purchase Order](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/payment/purchase-order.html)** payment method and insert the PO number that the customer should provide after s/he made the payment. Please check the link and find out more details, see if this could be feasible.
2. The admin can choose also **[Cash on delivery](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/payment/cash-on-delivery.html)** when placing the order and the customer pays when s/he receives the goods.
3. There's also the possibility to use the **[Bank Transfer](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/payment/bank-transfer.html)** when the admin places the order on the behalf of the client. Basically, the client receives the order email confirmation and the details needed for the bank transfer in the email and s/he can make the payment.

**It really depends on what suits your business needs**, what I listed above are just the cleanest ways to achieve this without having the client tell the admin sensitive data like credit card data, checks data, or other stuff. I would say these are the safest payment methods in your scenario.